# Is there a mathematical distinction between "on" and "in"?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

Is there any difference if I said a function on an interval or a function in an interval? or a vector field on a manifold versus a vector field in a manifold?

The main reason is because some online notes wrote $\vec v \in Vect(M)$ and explained in verbatim that this means a vector "on" a manifold.

Comment: In English, I'd never say "a function _in_ an interval", but, rather, _on_. And a vector field _on_ a manifold. But then "Vect(M)" might mean tangent vectors on $M$, or vector fields on $M$... who knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\color{red}{in}$ is usually used as belong ($\color{red}{\in}$) , for example $a$ in $[1,10]$ is the same like saying $a \in [1,10]$ which means that $1 \leq a \leq 10$

However, when you talk about functions and intervals. It is more common to see $\color{blue}{on}$ an interval rather than in an interval